# Async task in dialogfragment

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-dialogfragment

In an activity all i have to do to execute my AsyncTask is 
   new MyAsyncTas().execute
But it's not working in my DialogFragment i was wondering how to achieve this in a DialogFragment.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a new task and execute it:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... none) {
      ...
      return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void none) {
      ...
  }
}.execute();
```

Code above is embedded in `createDialog()`:

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
  switch (id) {
    case 1:
      Dialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this)
        .setTitle("Title")
        .setMessage("Message")
        .setPositiveButton("Execute", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                // code above ....
            }
          }
          ...
```